# Usage-based Licensing framework

Tags: c++, licensing

I am just trying to look at different licensing models and potential technical C++ implementations.

Suppose you have **a desktop application including several algorithms** (A1, A2, A3). This application is communicating with some server (potentially in the cloud). These "local" algos may be used independently. **Is there any solution/framework out there which could allow us to bill their usage independtly?**

For example, , one user uses algo A2 and A3. Before saving files, the software computes the final bill, sends it to some server, asks the user to pay it and generate the results file.

This would allow to ship a potentially expensive software "for free" to the users and without the risk for them to spend an enourmous amount of money upfront without being sure this software will actually be heavily used.

Related question: what are the risks?

Comment: The main question will be:  how clever/motivated are your users to subvert your payment model?  If they are business people who don't mind paying per use, and don't know how to hack an executable, a straightforward/insecure model will do fine.  OTOH if they are hackers who want to play your video game for free, you're going to have to be very clever to outsmart them...

Comment: Well, talking about video games, it seems to be related to what Blizard (and WoW) is using right?

Comment: Most of the time, this works the other way around.  The user pays for expensive computation, then the computation happens.  If you do the computation locally, before requiring them to pay, this is likely a broken model.  It may be good enough for your business model, but it will be terribly easy to avoid the payment step.  As someone answered already, you can increase the security if you make it so that there is at least one piece of the valuable computation that happens on the server (such as decryption, although I'd suggest something more fundamental to your computation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Though your Pricing model is feasible for large scale and probably same as what cloud offers.**
I don't think any native application would be scalable/feasible with this model.

Most of the License of software's that are too costly to buy for each user, they give a floater license and a cap limit of number of simultaneous users.

***Pay as you use*** is great but it is same as cloud computing but then question is simple.

> Do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Unless you don't want to invest in your own cloud server, you can easily put your application on other cloud.

If you are ready for investment into build and maintain your own cloud then you should go ahead.

**Edit:**
You can use web service or the payment method. Expose the web service for calculating the price to be incurred. I would personally use Java or C# for this purpose.
as java and C# have enough support for it, for the wrapper around the C++ code i would use any of the jni or C++/cli language support.

Another thing is, I have not come accross any open source tool for it, each web service has it's own requirements. You can get the architecture but no ready made work.

`C++ code`->`webservice`->`price billing`->`result returned to caller`.

**Regarding Technical Difficulties.**
It would not be possible to do things completely in C++, You may require many other tools with C++.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, we cannot "easily" put our application on the cloud. Our algos are working on big data and need real-time results. Cloud related lag is not an option unfortunately...;(

Comment: Clouds often offer low visibility and rains. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: You dont have to put your application completely on cloud. Only pricing model logic application can be put on cloud.Actual Application can then comminicate with cloud for bill generation(can be as Post/Pre Paid) while actual application execution happens on the local PC.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. Well yes, this is our current architecture. But my initial question was more about finding some already existing C++ framework which could help us see how to do this. Please edit your answers if you can. I am editing my question because it was not precise enough indeed. Best regards.

Comment: Does the above solution makes sense to you? I have edited my post as per it.

Comment: Thanks. This was the architecture we came with. I was just wondering if you could reuse some best practices somewhere. It seems not. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2):

Consider such a scenario:

The program processes the data on the customer's computer, produces some cryptic data at this stage and calls home (your server).

The server there decodes the data, makes the final analysis and sends info to the client "It will costs you X dollars to see the result. Do you want to proceed?"
If yes, the client makes the payment and gets the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is their any C++ framework for that or should we implement it all by ourselves?

Comment: The network part does not seem to be complicated and any client-server solution would suffice. So you may consider using simple sockets or more advanced solution like CORBA where you get some more functionality "for free" like cryptography. Finally you may look at the cloud offers that could relieve you from the burden of running your own server if it may represent a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are desperatly trying to find any C++ framework or open-source examples to help us implement this (and ensure we are on the right track). Best regards.

Comment: I suppose the payment processing may be the most tricky part. Check if PayPal services are suitable for you.